Validity of Derived Input Bounds for Composed Sigmoid Functions in Neural Networks
I'm working on inferring preconditions in neural networks. For simplicity, I'm using scalar variables (instead of vectors/matrices) to understand the core problem.
Problem:
Given a simple feed-forward network with scalar variables:
$out = mx + b$
$y = \sigma(out)$
$out_1 = my + b$
$Y_1 = \sigma(out_1)$
where:

$\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$ is the sigmoid activation function
$m > 0$ and $b$ are scalar parameters
$x$ is the input
$y$ is the intermediate output
$Y_1$ is the final output

I want to derive preconditions $P(x)$ such that if $x$ satisfies $P$, then after running the network, $Y_1 < \delta$ is guaranteed (where $0 < \delta < 1$). This question is based on Dijkstra's weakest precondition calculus (wp calculus), which is a formal system for deriving preconditions from postconditions in program verification. While traditionally used for imperative programs, I'm trying to apply this concept to neural networks to understand their behavior bounds.
My attempt:
Working backwards from $Y_1 < \delta$:

From $Y_1 < \delta$:
$\sigma(out_1) < \delta$
$-\ln(\frac{1-\delta}{\delta}) > out_1$
$-\ln(\frac{1-\delta}{\delta}) > my + b$

Let $K = \frac{-\ln(\frac{1-\delta}{\delta}) - b}{m}$
Therefore: $y < K$

Substituting $y = \sigma(mx + b)$:
$\frac{1}{1 + e^{-(mx + b)}} < K$

Solving for $x$:
$1 < K(1 + e^{-(mx + b)})$
$1 - K < Ke^{-(mx + b)}$
$\frac{1-K}{K} < e^{-(mx + b)}$
$\ln(\frac{1-K}{K}) < -(mx + b)$
$x < \frac{-\ln(\frac{1-K}{K}) - b}{m}$


Question:
Due to the non-linear nature of sigmoid functions, I'm unsure if this derived precondition on $x$ will always guarantee $Y_1 < \delta$. Is this derivation correct?
If not, is it because wp cannot be applied onto neural networks? I'm particularly concerned about the composition of two sigmoid functions and how their non-linearity affects the validity of the derived bounds.
PS: I don't have much experience posting in this forum. If this is the wrong place, kindly suggest a better stack forum to post on. LLMs were used to generate the text for this post.
